# Change text in text field according to link that has been clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following.

```
<div class="petsearch">
<input id="pet_search_input" class="" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="query" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Now if the user types dog in the text field then the below link looks like the following.

```
<a id="pets" href="#dog" onclick="main()">
<img title="Dog" alt="Dog" src="./images/dog.png">
</a>
```

Now if the user types cat then the link appears but looks like the following.

```
<a id="pets" href="#cat" onclick="main()">
<img title="Cat" alt="Cat" src="./images/cat.png">
</a>
```

So for that I have some jquery that looks like the following.

```
$("#pets").click(function () {
$("#hidden_content").hide("fast");
$("#yourpet").hide("fast");
$("#pet_search_input").hide("fast");
});
```

Now I also have the following on the same page next to each image that a text field will appear as follows.

```
<input type="text" id="pet-type">
```

The above input will put have a word appear as the value when the user clicks on the link. So if the link is #cat then the input will get the value something like Feline when the link is clicked. If the link has #dog then the input will get the value of mut when the user clicks the link that has #dog.

My goal is to have the above input type text to display the name of the animal when the user click the link. So if the user clicks the link and it the link says dog then the input will update to say dog. I don't know how to achieve this. But it is worth noting that #dog can be ?dog or &dog. Can someone please help me with achieve this.

**UPDATE** Thanks to @Alvin for giving this code which means I'm getting closer to what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$("#pets").click(function () {
    $("#hidden_content").hide("fast");
    $("#yourpet").hide("fast");
    $("#pet_search_input").hide("fast");
    var result = $("#pets").attr("href");
    result = result.replace("#","");
    $("#pet-type").attr("value",result);
});
```

But I think if should be something like the following.

```
$("#pets").click(function () {
    $("#hidden_content").hide("fast");
    $("#yourpet").hide("fast");
    $("#pet_search_input").hide("fast");
    if $("#pets").attr("href","#cat") then 
    $("pet-type".attr("value","Feline"); Else If
    if $("#pets").attr("href","#dog") then 
    $("pet-type".attr("value","mut");
});
```

The above code doesn't work but I think people should see what I'm trying to accomplish.

**UPDATE** I've also tried the following.

```
if $("#pets".attr("href","#cat"),$("#pet-type").attr("value","Feline");
if $("#pets".attr("href","#dog"),$("#pet-type").attr("value","Mut");
```

**SOLVED CLOSED**

Comment: I'm a little confused by this, what happens when they are typing and it is just "d" or "do" or something that doesn't match an image and anchor? Also the `isNumberKey()` looks like it wouldn't let you type "dog" or anything else besides numbers. Also, you showed two elements with the same id (pets), this will cause you problems.

Comment: post sample on jsFiddle and maybe rewrite your question

Comment: An error gets thrown. but I do plan on setting maxlength attribute and adding a min that can be typed. Only 3 letter words can be allowed.

Comment: @MichaelB. theirs underlying PHP code that communicates with MySQL  in there so it wont work on JS fiddle.

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro, you can view the source to get the html generated by PHP

Comment: Since issue is in jQuery code, we just need the client side could to examine.. HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Change the javascript to

```
$("#pets").click(function () {
    $("#hidden_content").hide("fast");
    $("#yourpet").hide("fast");
    $("#pet_search_input").hide("fast");
    var result = $("#pets").attr("href");
    if (result == "#cat"){
        $("#pet-type").attr("value","Feline");
    }
    if (result == "#dog"){
        $("#pet-type").attr("value","Mut");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alvin at this point that seems like a guess at what the OP wants since the question is pretty unclear. Also just FYI, check out [jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem like it will work, simply because OP has `pets` id defined multiple times and should be changed to use it as a `class` IMHO, not id value.

Comment: I think you put me on somewhat of the correct path. However I think it should be something along the lines of $("#pets-result").attr("value", predefined text depending on the link href);

Comment: @SolomonClosson, like mentioned above, #pets only appears once depending on the input.

I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need some kind of **IF** statement in here. `if $("#pets".attr("href","#cat") then $("#pet-type").attr("value","Feline")`

Comment: Updated. Is that what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks :) could you please tick my answer? Trying to gain point :P

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you want to do, this should respond your question:

```
// Called on link click
function main() {
    $("#pets-input").val($("#pets").attr("href").substr(1));
}
```

This will works assuming that the input is changed to `<input type="text" id="pets-input">` to avoid id conflicts.

Comment: But there are id conflicts with `pets` also defined multiple times.  What about that?

Comment: The id `pets` is defined once for the link, and once for the input. If he changes the id of the input, then it's fine.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at multiple links, Cat and Dog which I now realize that only 1 of these gets displayed at a time.  Still, this question is a bit confusing.